# FineUploader - how to get the url of uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a file fine and got the name of the file.. but all I want to do is be able to create an image  tag with the src being the file and I just cannot work out how to do it..

Here is the code..

$('#fine-uploader-newvisit').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/S3File/UploadFile'
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
        }

```
}).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {

    if (responseJSON.success) {

        viewModel.CurrentUser.PhotoFile(responseJSON.S3FileName);

        //http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-prefix/jpgs/sample.jpg
        document.write("<img src=http://s3.amazonaws.com/[myacesskeyhere]/S3File/UploadFile/" + responseJSON.S3FileName + ">");

    }

});
```

responseJSON.S3FileName contains the name of the file generated by amazon successfully but my test document.write shows a broken link.  I obviously am not generating the url correctly.
I tried it without the access key too, I tried adding a bucket name.. I just cannot work it out

Answer (score -1):

First off, **do not** use `document.write` to add HTML to your page. There are many ways to do this correctly, such as including an `<img>` in your static markup and adjusting the `src` attribute, or creating an element via `document.createElement` and adding the element to the DOM.

If you want to display an img from your S3 bucket, you have two options:

1. Make the object/bucket public
2. Generate a signed URL for the object server-side using the S3 SDK along with your secret key.

The latter example is [detailed in Fine Uploader's example S3 PHP server](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-s3-server/blob/master/endpoint.php#L211).